# REST and JQuery Request

Tags: jquery, json, rest, slim

i get this JSON from my REST:

```
{"users":[{"id_user":"1","firstname":"Admin","lastname":"Admin","mail":"admin@admin.de","password":"admin"}]}
```

and with follow code i want to parse the JSON response.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/REST/users",
     function(data) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.counters.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.counters[i];
    console.log(counter.counter_name);
} 
          });
```

but in the console i get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

I hope you can help me =/

Comment: also add dataType: "json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `getJSON` you don't need to convert your response to JSON manually. jQuery does that for you.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/REST/users",
 function(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.counters.length; i++) {
     var counter = data.counters[i];
     console.log(counter.counter_name);
   }
 });
```

Although keep in mind, that the JSON response you posted doesn't have a `counters` key, so I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve with this.